# Understanding Visual Foxpro 8.0 runtime

Tags: visual-foxpro

I don't know too much about Foxpro but I need it to review DBF files.

On my PC, I have installed a client file: "Visual FoxPro 8.0 client.msi".

Now I'm able to run an exe file of Visual Foxpro 8.0 from a folder where is copied:

[image]

I haven't installed any Visual Foxpro program, only client.

My question is: Do I still need a license for Visual Foxpro?

Comment: This link will describe the VFP8 license agreement: http://www.tedroche.com/Present/2003/RocheSoftwareLicensingPaper.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen VFP referred to as 'the client' before, but the directory structure you show in your screenshots looks like a full installation of VFP 8.  You'd run vfp8.exe to then access your DBF files.

Did it ask for a license/CD key during installation?

Comment: When installing Visual FoxProx client, it didn't prompt nor ask for any license number

Comment: @CarlosHeredia, sure looks full install, like someone did an MSI install of the entire VFP project and distributed to THEIR client... not cool

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a VFP client. 
The VFP runtime contains only a few DLL files.
VFP runtimes for all versions can be found here: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/FoxPro/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=125

Answer (score 0):

If curious about a license agreement for VFP8, check out this link. Otherwise, it looks like you have the full VFP8 install.

The .MSI probably had a copy of an existing VFP8 installation. So when ran, it just did a copy to a destination directory without requiring a CD key.

```
http://www.tedroche.com/Present/2003/RocheSoftwareLicensingPaper.pdf
```